# cannot access swift class from objective-c pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I have created a new single-view swift project, and then added a pod file (for `MWPhotobrowser`) and installed it. 
I can now do `import MWPhotobrowser` on top of `ViewController.swift` file and use this framework without problems.
but I need to make some changes to this pod by adding extra properties to `MWPhotoBrowser.h` file, one of these properties is a reference to `ViewController.swift` class.

I am aware of the following:
**A)** It's not a good practice to make changes on pod frameworks since `pod update` will overwrite these changes.
**B)** I can fork the main github repo and point cocoa pods to my fork.
**C)** I can download the frameworks form github and do not use cocoa pods at all.
But for my specific case, I need to access `ViewController` class from inside cocoa pods ?

things I've already tried:
**1)** `Defines Modules` set to yes in the main project as well as in the pods project
**2)** `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"`  gives file not found
**3)** dragged the file `ViewController.swift` into Pods project (the blue icon in project navigator), this gave me: `Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'MWPhotoBrowser.MWPhotoBrowserPrivate'` build error, which I've tried all possible solutions on SO to solve this error but to no avail ...
**4)** marked `ViewController` class with `@objc` attribute

and [here is a clean sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57066689/POC.zip).
how can I access `ViewController` swift-based class from inside pods ?

Comment: Why do you want to access it directly in MWPhotobrowser? Wouldn't it be easier and cleaner to achieve what you want with delegates?

Comment: I already tried the delegates pattern but i couldn't get it to work because it needs casting the delegate to swift's ViewController class so I can access its properties

Comment: Maybe you could create a protocol inside of the pod, and make `ViewController` to conform to this protocol. In protocol you would declare this property that you need to access.

Comment: this is already implemented and working but my question is how to access ViewController class from inside any file in the pod, like MWPhotoBrowser.m for example

Comment: if you **must** do it this way because the delegate pattern isn't what you want. Then I would suggest that for `MWPhotobrowser` don't use cocoapods, it's better to drag the source code into your project. Then you shouldn't have any problems with the imports. Tell me how it goes

Comment: does the reference *have to* be a ViewController.swift class? Can it be a ViewController ObjC class?  You haven't explained why it must be a .swift ViewController.  Also, why do you need to do this?  Just import, modify the pod to create your own custom init, then modify the init in your swift code.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @jungledev yes the reference have to be a swift based VC because the app is a swift app and I have to access & modify specific properties in that VC from the pod and this is a design requirement in my app. what do you mean by "just import" ? import the pod inside the swift's VC ? actually I need the opposite: importing the vc inside the pod which i can't do it until now

Comment: 1. import the pod 2. modify the pod's initializer code IN the pod 3. Call the modified init function from somewhere else in your app where you have also imported your VC. 4. Perform changes to both VC and Pod in this new class.  I'm essentially saying make both able to be modified independently, then modify them both in a separate file where you can import both.  Without a very detailed explanation about *WHY* you must do this, you probably won't get a good answer. Your problem is counter-intuitive to SOLID design and encapsulation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)