# how can I access my swift project files from pod file which is in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase

I am using firebase chat SDK which is in objective c  and now I need to access swift files in this SDK. Please help me out.

Comment: use bridge header

Comment: Use chat sdk pod.

Comment: you have to use swift files in your third party library which is in obj-C?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik bridge header how?

Comment: use of bridging header will solve your problem as answered below... @panktipatel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130806/cannot-access-swift-class-from-objective-c-pods I am facing the same problem. @HakikatSingh

Answer (score 1):

First create the bridging header for your project by:

1. Adding the new **.h** file(header file) to your project  and name it as

   **yourProjectname-Bridging-Header.h**

2.Then in the build settings of your project add the path of the bridging header.
[image]

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h
```

3. In your bridging header file

   *# import "frameworkname.h" // your framework's header file*

   Try to run the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create an header (.h) file that will expose the swift class you chose to expose to objective-c code
There are certain things to consider when doing so and they are all listed in this short [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: yes. I have referred this document before. but not getting the solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add **"TargetName-Swift.h"** where TargetName is the name of your project, where you want to acess the swift files

Comment: No , its simple

Comment: then you should clean and rebuild the project again